# Ruby / Rails 4.2.5 - Devise - before_action :authenticate_user - User plans page locked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I implemented devise authentication with a before_action on pages except landing. The only problem is, this now locks me out of the users plans page. I could easily permit the plans page as an exception, except the plans are partialed out on an alternative home page to be displayed when someone is not signed_in. I've tried allowing the home page as an exception but received an controller error (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PagesController#home). My question is 1.) Should I figure out a way to permit the else display and keep it partialed or should I reorganize the code and separate it all together?

Do I need to include additional files (routes?)

Also, If I formatted this question incorrectly, feel free to correct me. Thanks.

***home.html.erb***

```
<div class="row">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>

      <%= render 'users/home' %>

  <% else %>

      <%= render 'users/plans' %>        

  <% end %>
</div>
```

---

***pages_controller.rb***

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, except:  [:landing, :home]

def landing

end

def plans
end

def home
    @contributor_plan = Plan.find(1)
    @elitecontributor_plan = Plan.find(2)
    @technician_plan = Plan.find(3)
    @elitetechnician_plan = Plan.find(4)
    @center_plan = Plan.find(5)
    @elitecenter_plan = Plan.find(6)
    @affair_plan = Plan.find(7)
    @eliteaffair_plan = Plan.find(8)
end

end
```

---

Controller Error (when home is excepted from authentication)

[image]

Comment: Do you have Plan records in your database. If not, try to create some in your console by `10.times { Plan.create }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flash message is very obvious:

```
"RecordNotFound, Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1.
```

Please create at least 8 plans with ID from 1 to 8:

```
8.times do |i|
 Plan.create(...., id: i+1)
end
```

Comment: I unknowingly dropped my DB. I had these plans records at one point, hence my confusion as to why they no longer existed. Once I verified that the db was empty, I re-added my plans manually via rails console